# Intermittent issue with stored procedure execution in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am getting the below exception in application logs.

```
3~Error in xxxxImpl execute method :  org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call xxx.GETxxx(?, ?, ?, , , , , ?, ?, , ?, ?, ?, )}, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 12; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 12
```

When i do an application restart or app server restart the issue is gone.

It re-occurs again after some time say in 3 to 4 days time!

The application is working fine otherwise than this intermittent issue.

I am using spring.framework.version - 3.2.5.RELEASE.

For calling stored procedures from Java, am using org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.

Comment: Look here it gives you a hint: `java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 12`

Comment: The problem is that this issue goes away when i do a restart of the application or application server. If its an issue with parameter missing, then it should occur always right?

Comment: Or it is a special call!!

Comment: SImilar issue here..http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/31175-getting-sql-state-null-error-code-17041-missing-in-or-out-parameter-at-index

Comment: what is the stored procedure doing? Could be it is called only sometimes

Comment: Stored Procedure is working fine, i guess there is a problem in the Spring framework which is missing the parameters while doing the below  call xxx.GETxxx(?, ?, ?, , , , , ?, ?, , ?, ?, ?, )}, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved after using ojdbc6.jar.

I was using ojdbc14.jar for JDK 6 environment :).